# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Lets say we have the integral:$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}+z^2dz$$ 
and we would like to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here for complex numbers. Now, we let $\gamma$ be any curve connecting $-1+i$ to $2+2i$ such that $Im(z)>0$.

I'm having some trouble using the FTC for this. I wanted to say that we can separate this into two integrals: $$\int_{-1+i}^{2+2i}z^2dz+ \int_\gamma\frac{1}{z}dz.$$ Now we can apply the FTC on the first integral since we know $\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{z^3}{3})=z^2$ and just compute it. For the second integral I'm having trouble. I want to say that the integral equals zero because if we take the branch cut $$-\pi <\arg(z)<\pi$$for $\log|z|+i\arg(z)$ we know that it is the derivative of $\log(z)$ for the given branch cut. I'm not sure how to solve the second integral.

edit: If I take the branch cut $-\frac{3\pi}{2}<\arg(z)<\frac{3\pi}{2}$, would my answer be:

$$\int_{-1+i}^{2+2i}z^2+\frac{1}{z}dz = (\frac{z^3}{3}+\log(z))|_{-1+i}^{2+2i}? $$

edit 2: I was thinking, why can't we apply Cauchy's theorem for the second integral and get 0 because we never actually cross the singularity z=0?

edit 3: I guess from the assumption that we have we don't know if the curve is indeed closed, so now I understand why we can't apply Cauchy's theorem and must use the FTC as I have.

Comment: Deform your contour around the branch cut and you may apply the fundamental theorem.  That is, don't permit $\gamma$ to cross your branch cut. Of course, given a non-closed curve, you can choose a branch cut judiciously to avoid the path's crossing it.  The branch cut need not be a straight line.

Comment: @Dr.MV Would you be willing to elaborate on how I would do this? If I use the branch cut I've chosen, what would our second integral give us? I'm not sure how to apply it here. Would we just use our bounds like the first integral and compute?

Comment: @Dr.MV Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Your last line in the edit seems correct to me, since the path $\gamma$ does not touch the cut.

Comment: @mickep I took a different branch cut this time, I took the negative imaginary axis. Also, If I split the two integrals and added them together, for example computing for $z^2$ and adding that to $1/z$ I would get the same answer, I assume, correct?

Comment: Same answer indeed.

Comment: @mickep I was thinking, why can't we just apply Cauchy's Theorem and say that the second integral (1/z) is equal to zero because we know z+1/z is analytic other than at z=0 but our curve will never cross that point since we have the imaginary part > 0? And if this is true then doesn't that mean my answer is incorrect?

Comment: @mickep Or can we not use Cauchy's Theorem here?

Comment: Your curve is not closed, so why should the integral be zero?

Comment: I guess from the assumption that we have we don't know if the curve is indeed closed, so now I understand why we can't apply Cauchy's theorem and must use the FTC as I have.